# Bibliography Program Java

Tags: java, arrays, bufferedreader, rank

I am trying to create a program that reads in an unalphabetized bibliography textfile, then prints out the newly alphabetized one. I have gotten to the point where my program recognizes the first letter of each line (which I printed out to be certain), but I don't know how to implement code so that the program can rearrange the lines in alphabetical order.

Here is my updated code without using the displayCorrectBib method, I still have no output though:

```
package hw6;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Hw6 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
//read in a works cited text file
        BufferedReader fin = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Bibliography.txt"));

//        String line = null;  

        displayIncorrectBib(fin);

        ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();

        while ((line = fin.readLine()) != null) {
            lines.add(line);
        }

        Collections.sort(lines);

        for (String s : lines) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }

        displayCorrectBib(lines);


        fin.close();                //close BufferedReader
    }
    public static String line;
    public static char[] stringArray;

    public static void displayIncorrectBib(BufferedReader fin) throws Exception {

        System.out.println("Incorrectly Alphabetized Bibliography:");

        while ((line = fin.readLine()) != null) {

            toChar(line);                            //call toChar to convert string to char

            System.out.println(line);             //print unalphabetized bibliography on separate lines

        }
        System.out.println();

    }
    public static char[] letters = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M',
        'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'};

    public static char toChar(String line) {
        //convert string line to character array
        stringArray = line.toCharArray();

        System.out.println(stringArray[0]);

        return stringArray[0];
    }

    public static void displayCorrectBib(List<String> lines) {
        System.out.println("Correctly alphabetized Bibliography: ");


    }
}
```

Comment: post sample text file

Comment: Searles, Baird, and Martin Last. A Reader's Guide to Science Fiction. New York: Facts on File, Inc., 1979.
Boorstin, Daniel J. The Creators: A History of the Heroes of the Imagination. New York: Random, 1992. 
Toomer, Jean. Cane. Ed. Darwin T. Turner. New York: Norton, 1988.
Hall, Donald, ed. The Oxford Book of American Literacy Anecdotes. New York: Oxford UP, 1981.
Allen, Thomas B. Vanishing Wildlife of North America. Washington, D.C.: National Geographic Society, 1974.

Comment: ^^ these are the bibliographical sources that I'm trying to print in alphabetical order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use sort?

```
ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
String line;
while ((line = fin.readLine()) != null) {
       lines.add( line );
}

Collections.sort(lines);
```

And to display:

```
public static void displayCorrectBib( List<String> lines ) {
    for( String s : lines )
    {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Here it is in whole form:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    //read in a works cited text file
    BufferedReader fin = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Bibliography.txt"));

    ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    String line;
    while ((line = fin.readLine()) != null) {
        lines.add( line );
    }

    Collections.sort(lines);

    for( String s : lines )
    {
        System.out.println(s);
    }

    fin.close();                //close BufferedReader
}
```

Comment: Note: This won't work if you do it *after* `displayIncorrectBib`, as `fin` will then be empty. Also, I think `Arrays.sort` is just for arrays. Use `Collections.sort` instead.

Comment: How do I print the alphabetized code? in the displayCorrectBib method?

Comment: I'm getting a compiler error that reads " for each not applicable to expression type" I may not be calling my method correctly, or writing the correct argument in displayCorrectBib.

Comment: @user2532816: Try the above.

Comment: unfortunately I'm not seeing any output

Comment: Probably from using methods, try last thing I just added.

Comment: My apologies! I was putting it after displayIncorrectBib. Problem solved. Thank you!!!